# How to get rid of : Scripting runtime error: cannot convert to a number, "[a IloNumExpr]" error

Tags: optimization, syntax-error, cplex, ilog

i'm still a beginner in ILOG CPLEX STUDIO.

I have some decision variable such as:

```
dvar int gamma [Operations][Operations]in 0..1;
```

to calculate some of the deductible variable,
I use an "execute" block in which I want a variable to have the value of gamma[0][0] + 1:

```
execute{
 var a = gamma[0][0] + 1;
}
```

this code return me the error :

```
Scripting runtime error: cannot convert to a number, "[a IloNumExpr]".
```

I believe this has something to do with the fact that gamma is a decision variable but I don't know to get the value inside of gamma[0][0]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are 3 ways to compute e

```
range Operations=0..2;

dvar int gamma [Operations][Operations]in 0..1;

dexpr int e1= gamma[0][0] + 1;

subject to
{
  
}

int e2= gamma[0][0] + 1;
int e3;
execute
{
  e3= gamma[0][0] + 1;
}

execute
{
  writeln(e1,e2,e3);
}
```

Comment: Just to add to Alex's answer, don't forget that the decision variables don't usually have any specific value until after a solution has been found.

Comment: Hi Alex, this is second time you help me in my Cplex problem so thanks a lot !

Comment: Your answer made me realise that the error come from the fact that i wrote the "execute" that is suposed to calculate the values of the implication variables before the "subject to" that has to calculate the decision variable.